# Unable to parse Gujarati text in JSON

Tags: java, json, web-services

I have developed a web service which is running on JBOSS-EAP. I have a JSON which include Gujarati language which I am unable to parse.

While parsing Gujarati fonts question marks come in the output.
I have searched and found I have to change the encoding to UTF-8 and then it will work. I don't know whether it is a correct solution, but regardless of that I have tried many ways but failed.

```
//code for getting data from JSON
JSONObject obj = object.getJSONObject("data");
obj.optString("Name");

//changed web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

//changed encoding by this
byte ptext[] = myString.getBytes();
String value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: `I have searched the and found i have to change encoading to UTF-8 and then it will work. Don't know weather it is correct solution` Try and let us know.

Comment: `But regardless of that have tried many ways but failed` Please add what all you have tried and what issue you faced while trying that.

Comment: check: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3456721, https://access.redhat.com/solutions/393133, https://oneweb.tech/api/Step7WildFlyEncodingandUndertow.html

Answer (score 0):

I am using spring-boot 2, I think it has nothing to do with server, we just need to add charset as utf-8
I am able to get Gujarati text from web service.

sample request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/comment/locale", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String addCommentInLocale(@RequestBody Map<String,String> comment) {
    return comment.get("guj");
}
```

Curl request:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/comment/locale \
  -H 'Accept-Charset: utf-8' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "guj":"દુનિયા"
}'
```

Sample images which show the request and response:

[image: ide]

[image: postman]

Answer (score 0):

You need to do below change : may be it may help you

Add

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")
```

before calling

```
getParameter()
```